# writing a date to the spreadsheet with vbscript

Tags: openoffice-calc

I am using vbscript to query a mysql database and then populate the results into an openoffice calc file.

All seemed to be going well until I tried to enter a date into the spreadsheet using

```
objSheet.getCellByPosition(2, n).SetString(adoRS("DATEONLY"))
```

This enters some strange symbols which is entirely wrong.

So I tried entering the date as a string intsead of a date, i.e the type is a string from mysql instead of a date and this sort of worked, but when inserted into calc it adds an apostrophe to the start of the string which means calc does not treat it as a date any more!

What am I doing wrong? I have spent hours searching google for this but cannot find a solution.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I've never used OpenOffice but in Excel it can sometimes help to format the spreadsheet column *before* setting it's value. Have you tried setting the data type of your spreadsheet column to a "date" type first?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems it likes to have an integer sent to the cell, and then set the cell to date.

Answer (score 0):

I try insert into cell a date without problem, also you can try format date and you has the possibility to insert a formula.

For my tests I tried:

```
Call oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1").setString(Now)

Call oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A2").setString(Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY"))

Call oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A3").setFormula("=DATE(2016;02;05")
```

Would be change the variable `Now` to your `adoRS("DATEONLY")`